# Can I use a power only USB lead to connect Rpi and HDMIPi?

Tags: usb-power

The HDMIPi assembly was originally designed for Raspberry Pi A, with a short lead supplied to power the RPi from the HDHMI driver board. When an RPi B+ or RPi 2 is used, the supplied lead is not suitable for the different disposition of the sockets, as it won't bend into a configuration that will not foul other parts of the assembly. It would be nice to be able to use a flexible, power only, mobile phone charger type, USB lead instead.

I haven't been able to find circuit diagrams to confirm that only the power connections are needed in this cable, so, to be safe, my question is: can I use a power only, mobile phone charger type, USB lead to connect RPi to the HDMI board in an HDMIPi assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the same. As soon as I posted this question I found that Adafruit publish a circuit diagram for the Raspberry Pi 2 that answers this  perfectly, since the only connections to the USB power socket on the left side of the diagram are the two power leads. [image: circuit diagram for the Raspberry Pi 2]